# php drop down button selected

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

in form edit data wants to display in the form...but  drop down values should not get selected ...i want drop down value get seleted
here is code in list_search function id return cmb_fruit, val return Apple or Orange

```
              <tr>
                <td width="38%" height="28" align="left"><span class="style20"><font color="#DC143C">*</font>Profession</span></td>
                <td width="62%" align="left"><label for="profession"></label>
                  <select name="cmb_fruit" size="1" id="cmb_fruit">
                    <option value="Select">Select</option>
                    <option value="Apple">Apple</option>
                    <option value="Orange">Orange</option>
                  </select>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        list_search('cmb_fruit',<?php echo "'" . @mysql_result($rs_modify,0,'fruit') . "'";?>)
    </script>
                  </td>
              </tr>


function list_search(id,val)
 {
 cnt=document.getElementById(id).length
 for(x=0; x<cnt; x++ )
 {
     if( document.getElementById(id).options(x).value==val)
     {

         document.getElementById(id).options(x).selected=true
         break;
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using Javascript for this rather than just adding the "selected" attribute to the matching option using PHP? Not that using Javascript to bind data to a form is a bad idea, but it's only going to save time vs. doing it in PHP if you use a Javascript library designed for this sort of thing, e.g. KnockoutJS or CanJS.

Answer (score 0):

```
var fruit = document.getElementById("fruit");
fruit.options[fruit.options.selectedIndex].selected = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `value` property of the select. Also, make sure the `list_search` function is declared in the `head` if you are calling it from a script that runs in the body.

```
function list_search(id, val) {
    document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}
```

Note that you don't need javascript for this and you could simpy put the `selected` attribute on the `option` element you want to select.

```
<option value="Apple" selected>Apple</option>
```